# Why pages with figures are converted to image (not editable) after submitted pdf is line-numbered by IEEE ACCESS

Tags: pdf, ieeeaccess

We have recently submitted a pdf manuscript to IEEE Access. When checking the proof (generated by IEEE ACCESS) at the end of the submission portal, we find our pdf file with its lines numbered on the left. However, all pages which accommodate figures (except one instance) are converted to images and hence are not editable. This is why the manuscript has been returned to us for resubmission. I wonder if someone has had the same experience and can share any workaround. Just to make it clear, we just submitted the pdf file, not the latex source files and the manuscript is OK in our side before submission.

Cheers
Hooman

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the given information it is unclear if this is a TeX problem or one related to the submission tool. Please provide more information and a MWE if you think it is TeX related.

Comment: Please, can you allow at least one full day before you ask to close a question? Closing a question in a few hours only makes sense if it is a spam, which is not the case here.